# Access violation when accessing an empty map inside a nested class

Tags: c++

I have some code that includes three classes.
The relevant class structure includes the following:

- class1 contains a pointer to an instance of class2
- class2 contains a private class3 class, and a function to access a reference to class 3
- class3 contains a private map class and a function to check if the map is empty

The problem I am having is when I set this up like so I get an access violation:

```
bool result = class1->class2->GetProperties().CheckEmpty();
```

But if I set it up like this I don't have any errors:

```
bool result = class2->GetProperties().CheckEmpty();
```

Why would adding another class layer suddenly cause this problem?

Here is the code I am using to reproduce the error.
The two lines in the in main do not produce an error but comment those and uncomment the other two and you will get the error.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <map>

class PropertySet 
{
    public:
        PropertySet::PropertySet(){};
        PropertySet::~PropertySet(){};

        bool CheckEmpty() const { return properties.empty(); }

    private:
        std::map< std::string, std::string > properties;
};

class Tile 
{
public:
    Tile::Tile() {};
    Tile::~Tile() {};

    // Get a set of properties regarding the tile.
    const PropertySet &GetProperties() const { return properties; }

private:

    PropertySet properties;
};

class Tileset 
{
public:
    Tileset::Tileset(){};
    Tileset::~Tileset(){};

    Tile* tile;
};

int main()
{
    bool test = false;

    //NO error-----------------------------
    Tile* t = new Tile();
    test = t->GetProperties().CheckEmpty();
    //-------------------------------------

    //ERROR--------------------------------
    //Tileset* t = new Tileset();
    //test = t->tile->GetProperties().CheckEmpty();
    //-------------------------------------

    delete t;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you construct a new Tileset, the pointer to Tile is uninitialized.

```
Tileset::Tileset(){};
Tileset::~Tileset(){};
```

should be

```
Tileset::Tileset(){ tile = new Tile(); };
Tileset::~Tileset(){ delete tile; };
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I actually have a deeper problem in the library. I was trying to shorten the amount of code and still reproduce the problem but it's just not happening unless I use the library.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using Visual Studio since you have a stdafx.h included. Debugging a library can be annoying but I usually just set a breakpoint before the call that gives an access violation and step through line-by-line to examine each pointer value looking for garbage. Access violation is very likely an uninitialized pointer.